# How to convert numbers into characters?

Tags: python

So I'm just getting started with Python/coding and wrote the following simple script.

```
text = raw_input('Enter text: ') # get text
textr = text[::-1] # reverse the order
textl = [] # make it a list
for c in textr: # convert chr to ord
    n = ord(c)
    textl.append(n) 
print str(textl)
```

So if I enter `'Ryan 123'` it outputs the list `'[51, 50, 49, 32, 110, 97, 121, 82]'`.

What I can't figure out is how to convert the string `'51, 50, 49, 32, 110, 97, 121, 82'` back into the string `'Ryan 123'`.

Here's what I tried:

```
textn = raw_input('Enter text: ')
textl = map(int, textn.split(" ,"))
for i in textl:
    n = chr(i)
    textl.append(n)
print str(textl)
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn text to list of characters by `list(text)` or whatever else, what expects iterable.

`map` is applying a function on each item of iterable:

```
>>> text = "Ryan 123"
>>> nums = map(ord, text)
>>> nums
[82, 121, 97, 110, 32, 49, 50, 51]
```

`chr` turns number to character

```
>>> chr(82)
'R'
```

Applying `chr` on all numbers creates a list of characters:

```
>>> map(chr, nums)
['R', 'y', 'a', 'n', ' ', '1', '2', '3']
```

To have all the characters joind, call `"".join`:

```
>>> "".join(map(chr, nums))
'Ryan 123'
```

Answer (score 0):

You reversed the order when you have converted into a list of ASCII values. So you need to reverse again the order when you are converting back:

```
>>> textl
[51, 50, 49, 32, 110, 97, 121, 82]
>>> text = []
>>> for i in textl:
...     text.append(chr(i))
...
>>> text
['3', '2', '1', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'y', 'R']
>>> text.reverse()
>>> text
['R', 'y', 'a', 'n', ' ', '1', '2', '3']
>>>
```

---

You can do your operation in two lines in fact:

```
>>> text = "Ryan 123"
>>> text_ord = reversed(map(ord, text))
>>> text_back = reversed(map(chr, text_ord))  # returns an iterator
>>> "".join(text_back)
'Ryan 123'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping and appending to the same list `textl`

```
textn = raw_input('Enter text: ')
textl = map(int, textn.split(","))
s = [chr(i) for i in textl]
print "".join(reversed(s))
```

Comment: Actually I like Maxime solution better.